# File sent by Nearby not opening

Tags: google-nearby

I'm starting to work with Nearby, and sending a file over the stream. I see on the sender's side that the file is sent, and on the receiver's side I see both the `onPayloadReceived` event and 2 `onPayloadTransferUpdate` events, the second with a status of 1. Once I get that  event with status 1, I run the following code:

```java
Payload payload = payloads.remove(id);
try {
    Payload.File payloadFile = payload.asFile();
    Reader reader;
    File file = payloadFile.asJavaFile();
    if (file==null)
        reader = new FileReader(payloadFile.asParcelFileDescriptor().getFileDescriptor());
    else
        reader = new FileReader(file);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    char[] buff = new char[1024];
    do
    {
        int count = reader.read(buff);
        if (count<=0)
            break;
        builder.append(buff, 0, count);
    }while(true);

    receivedData.setText(builder);
}
catch (Exception exn){Log.d(TAG, "Exception thrown while receiving",exn);}
```

The result is that `file` is null, and the `read` command throws an `IOException` with the message `read failed: EBADF (Bad file number)`. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Could you show the code that corresponds to you "sending a file over the stream"?

I ask because STREAM and FILE are 2 different Payload types, so if you send as a STREAM (regardless of whether the contents of the STREAM came from a file), you will receive as a STREAM.